# How to work on several Python packages in the same Vscode workspace?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

I am leaving PyCharm which was too automated and was preventing me from learning properly what is under the hood. Now I am learning Vscode and am trying to figure out how to work on several Python packages at the same time.

I have an app1 package, which was also the original Vscode workspace. I added two folders to my workspace, which are lib1 and lib2, which are used by app1.

How to set app1 settings.json to include lib1 and lib2 in the linting and debugging?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I usually set the lib1 and lib2 paths at PYTHONPATH variable inside my .env file. This .env file is located at workspace directory.

For example...

```py
PYTHONPATH=${PYTHONPATH}:./lib1:./lib2
```